# Performing schema evolution after OSGi bundle started / stopped

Tags: database-design, osgi

I have an OSGi application. Each OSGi module consists of some business logic and **data model**. I am planning to do schema evolution each time the **new** module is started for the very first time. As I mentioned above, each module contains data model which extends application's core data model. Thus I need to create some new tables before the new module starts.

The only solution I can think of is the **extender pattern**. In other words there will be a module called `db-schema-extender` which will wait for implementations of `DbSchemaEvolutionService`. Implementation of this service will be provided by each module which is willing to extend application's core data model. When such implementation will be reqistered in OSGi service registry then the `db-schema-extender` will call  `DbSchemaEvolutionService.getEntities()` method to acquire list of entities and then the `db-schema-extender` will perform the `schemaExport(List<Object> entities)` to create tables required by the new module.

Do you have any experience with similar problem?

What was your solution?

What do you think of solution I proposed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have experience with problem similar to yours. 
I think your solution will work, but I don't know if there is a better solution.
My solution is a little different: rather than have the service **DbSchemaEvolutionService**, I add a new header in the **MANIFEST** file that list all entities that this bundle contains.
The module **db-schema-extender** like yours will listen to bundle start and stop event to add or remove these entities from managing entities.

Comment: Thanks. Putting the entities to MANIFEST seems to be definitely a better solution than creating `DbSchemaEvolutionService`.

Comment: This is the recommended approach. One pitfall, you're bundle might get started before the migration has completed. Best solution to this is to have a special service that the modules can depend on. Its presence would then signal that any migration has concluded.